# How do I convert a Query to a Stored Function?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

I have a query that returns a single column of Zip codes based on 2 variables. How do I make it return the same table as a stored function? I have created ones that return a single result based on whatever variables but I can't seem to make it return a table.

```
select zone_id
  from(Select zone_id, distance, case when distance between 0 and 20 then 1 when distance between 21 and 50 then 2 when distance between 51 and 100 then 3 when distance between 101 and 150 then 4 else 5 end as bucket  
          From(select zone_id,city,province,terminal_zone, DIST_BETWEEN_ZONES((select postal_code from zone where zone_id = :TERMINAL ),zone_id) as distance 
                    from zone where service_type = 'DIRECT' and zone_id in (select zone_id from terminal_multi where terminal_zone = :TERMINAL))) where bucket = :Bucket
```

Comment: Why not a view instead?

Comment: The company we License our Software from dictates we can't Create Tables or Views but can create triggers and stored Functions.

Comment: show us the code for your function that returns a single value

Answer (score 0):

The key is to declare a cursor, open it and leave it open when the procedure ends.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc (
    IN pTerminal INT
    ,IN pBucket INT
    ) LANGUAGE SQL DYNAMIC result sets 1

BEGIN
    DECLARE rtn_cur CURSOR WITH RETURN
    FOR
    SELECT zone_id
    FROM (
        SELECT zone_id
            ,distance
            ,CASE 
                WHEN distance BETWEEN 0
                        AND 20
                    THEN 1
                WHEN distance BETWEEN 21
                        AND 50
                    THEN 2
                WHEN distance BETWEEN 51
                        AND 100
                    THEN 3
                WHEN distance BETWEEN 101
                        AND 150
                    THEN 4
                ELSE 5
                END AS bucket
        FROM (
            SELECT zone_id
                ,city
                ,province
                ,terminal_zone
                ,DIST_BETWEEN_ZONES((
                        SELECT postal_code
                        FROM zone
                        WHERE zone_id = pTerminal
                        ), zone_id) AS distance
            FROM zone
            WHERE service_type = 'DIRECT'
                AND zone_id IN (
                    SELECT zone_id
                    FROM terminal_multi
                    WHERE terminal_zone = pTerminal
                    )
            )
        )
    WHERE bucket = pBucket;

    OPEN rtn_cur;
END
```